# uncaught typerror: cannot read property '167' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

i am reaching out to the SO community to see if you can help answer this problem of mine, i'm getting a JS error when using woocommerce (i have contacted them but have not heard back and its completely causing the site to not function) as payment buttons do not appear.

The file that causes the error is "add-to-cart-variation.min.js" and the code is as follows:

```
/*!
* Variations Plugin
*/(function(e,t,n,r){e.fn.wc_variation_form=function(){e.fn.wc_variation_form.find_matching_variations=function(t,n){var r=[];for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++){var s=t[i],o=s.variation_id;e.fn.wc_variation_form.variations_match(s.attributes,n)&&r.push(s)}return r};e.fn.wc_variation_form.variations_match=function(e,t){var n=!0;for(attr_name in e){var i=e[attr_name],s=t[attr_name];i!==r&&s!==r&&i.length!=0&&s.length!=0&&i!=s&&(n=!1)}return n};this.unbind("check_variations update_variation_values found_variation");this.find(".reset_variations").unbind("click");this.find(".variations select").unbind("change focusin");$form=this.on("click",".reset_variations",function(t){e(this).closest(".variations_form").find(".variations select").val("").change();var n=e(this).closest(".product").find(".sku"),r=e(this).closest(".product").find(".product_weight"),i=e(this).closest(".product").find(".product_dimensions");n.attr("data-o_sku")&&n.text(n.attr("data-o_sku"));r.attr("data-o_weight")&&r.text(r.attr("data-o_weight"));i.attr("data-o_dimensions")&&i.text(i.attr("data-o_dimensions"));return!1}).on("change",".variations select",function(t){$variation_form=e(this).closest(".variations_form");$variation_form.find("input[name=variation_id]").val("").change();$variation_form.trigger("woocommerce_variation_select_change").trigger("check_variations",["",!1]);e(this).blur();e().uniform&&e.isFunction(e.uniform.update)&&e.uniform.update()}).on("focusin touchstart",".variations select",function(t){$variation_form=e(this).closest(".variations_form");$variation_form.trigger("woocommerce_variation_select_focusin").trigger("check_variations",[e(this).attr("name"),!0])}).on("check_variations",function(n,r,i){var s=!0,o=!1,u=!1,a={},f=e(this),l=f.find(".reset_variations");f.find(".variations select").each(function(){e(this).val().length==0?s=!1:o=!0;if(r&&e(this).attr("name")==r){s=!1;a[e(this).attr("name")]=""}else{value=e(this).val();a[e(this).attr("name")]=value}});var c=parseInt(f.data("product_id")),h=f.data("product_variations");h||(h=t.product_variations[c]);h||(h=t.product_variations);h||(h=t["product_variations_"+c]);var p=e.fn.wc_variation_form.find_matching_variations(h,a);if(s){var d=p.shift();if(d){f.find("input[name=variation_id]").val(d.variation_id).change();f.trigger("found_variation",[d])}else{f.find(".variations select").val("");i||f.trigger("reset_image");alert(woocommerce_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text)}}else{f.trigger("update_variation_values",[p]);i||f.trigger("reset_image");r||f.find(".single_variation_wrap").slideUp("200")}o?l.css("visibility")=="hidden"&&l.css("visibility","visible").hide().fadeIn():l.css("visibility","hidden")}).on("reset_image",function(t){var n=e(this).closest(".product"),i=n.find("div.images img:eq(0)"),s=n.find("div.images a.zoom:eq(0)"),o=i.attr("data-o_src"),u=i.attr("data-o_title"),a=i.attr("data-o_alt"),f=s.attr("data-o_href");o!=r&&i.attr("src",o);f!=r&&s.attr("href",f);if(u!=r){i.attr("title",u);s.attr("title",u)}a!=r&&i.attr("alt",a)}).on("update_variation_values",function(t,n){$variation_form=e(this).closest(".variations_form");$variation_form.find(".variations select").each(function(t,r){current_attr_select=e(r);current_attr_select.data("attribute_options")||current_attr_select.data("attribute_options",current_attr_select.find("option:gt(0)").get());current_attr_select.find("option:gt(0)").remove();current_attr_select.append(current_attr_select.data("attribute_options"));current_attr_select.find("option:gt(0)").removeClass("active");var i=current_attr_select.attr("name");for(num in n)if(typeof n[num]!="undefined"){var s=n[num].attributes;for(attr_name in s){var o=s[attr_name];if(attr_name==i)if(o){o=e("<div/>").html(o).text();o=o.replace(/'/g,"\\'");o=o.replace(/"/g,'\\"');current_attr_select.find('option[value="'+o+'"]').addClass("active")}else current_attr_select.find("option:gt(0)").addClass("active")}}current_attr_select.find("option:gt(0):not(.active)").remove()});$variation_form.trigger("woocommerce_update_variation_values")}).on("found_variation",function(t,n){var i=e(this),s=e(this).closest(".product"),o=s.find("div.images img:eq(0)"),u=s.find("div.images a.zoom:eq(0)"),a=o.attr("data-o_src"),f=o.attr("data-o_title"),l=o.attr("data-o_alt"),c=u.attr("data-o_href"),h=n.image_src,p=n.image_link,d=n.image_title,v=n.image_alt;i.find(".variations_button").show();i.find(".single_variation").html(n.price_html+n.availability_html);if(a==r){a=o.attr("src")?o.attr("src"):"";o.attr("data-o_src",a)}if(c==r){c=u.attr("href")?u.attr("href"):"";u.attr("data-o_href",c)}if(f==r){f=o.attr("title")?o.attr("title"):"";o.attr("data-o_title",f)}if(l==r){l=o.attr("alt")?o.attr("alt"):"";o.attr("data-o_alt",l)}if(h&&h.length>1){o.attr("src",h).attr("alt",v).attr("title",d);u.attr("href",p).attr("title",d)}else{o.attr("src",a).attr("alt",l).attr("title",f);u.attr("href",c).attr("title",f)}var m=i.find(".single_variation_wrap"),g=s.find(".product_meta").find(".sku"),y=s.find(".product_weight"),b=s.find(".product_dimensions");g.attr("data-o_sku")||g.attr("data-o_sku",g.text());y.attr("data-o_weight")||y.attr("data-o_weight",y.text());b.attr("data-o_dimensions")||b.attr("data-o_dimensions",b.text());n.sku?g.text(n.sku):g.text(g.attr("data-o_sku"));n.weight?y.text(n.weight):y.text(y.attr("data-o_weight"));n.dimensions?b.text(n.dimensions):b.text(b.attr("data-o_dimensions"));m.find(".quantity").show();!n.is_in_stock&&!n.backorders_allowed&&i.find(".variations_button").hide();n.min_qty?m.find("input[name=quantity]").attr("min",n.min_qty).val(n.min_qty):m.find("input[name=quantity]").removeAttr("min");n.max_qty?m.find("input[name=quantity]").attr("max",n.max_qty):m.find("input[name=quantity]").removeAttr("max");if(n.is_sold_individually=="yes"){m.find("input[name=quantity]").val("1");m.find(".quantity").hide()}m.slideDown("200").trigger("show_variation",[n])});$form.trigger("wc_variation_form");return $form};e(function(){e(".variations_form").wc_variation_form();e(".variations_form .variations select").change()})})(jQuery,window,document);
```

Hope im doing the right thing by posting here quite new the to community :)

I wonder if its a theme issue causing this or of this JS code is invalid?

[image]

Comment: What line of YOUR code is the problem occurring on. Unfortunately, that minified file is going to be pretty useless.

Comment: My friend, You need to learn to use dev tools under Chrome or Firebug under Firefox. Enjoy

Comment: Yes, because we all love looking through one line of minified code for errors, when we don't know what we're looking for, because the variable names are all compressed

Comment: @tymeJV  I do apologise all, that was my ignorance. Okay so ive used chromes console (which is how i found out about the problem)

and here is what chrome says:

First line: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '175' of undefined add-to-cart-variation.min.js?ver=2.0.18:3`

Second Line: `Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. ping:1`

Comment: @helloworld - i've attached a screenshot above does this help at all?